"for what it's worth — used to say that one/someone is not sure whether something one/someone is about to say will be helpful or valued"
merriam-webster.com:
(1) for what it's worth — used to say that one is not sure whether something one is about to say will be helpful or valued
The word "one" seems a little awkward to me here.
Wouldn't it be better if we used "someone" instead?:
(2) for what it's worth — used to say that someone is not sure whether something someone is about to say will be helpful or valued
Is there any difference between (1) and (2)?

"One" multiple times in a row always refers to the same person. It's a more formal version of the general "you" we use when we want to talk about things a generic person might or can do.
"Someone" usually refers to a new person each time it's used. To refer back to the same "someone", we use a pronoun, in this case "they" since the gender isn't specified. "Someone ... they" would mean the same thing here, but "someone ... someone" would indicate two different people.
"One" is restricted to a relatively formal register, but that's how dictionaries are written, so there's nothing awkward about the way it's used here.

Unsurprisingly, the M-W version is correct and natural. It is acceptable to repeat "one" as it refers in general to the idea of a person.
"Someone", however, refers to an individual, even if an indefinite individual. It cannot be repeated because once used, we know who the person is, so we have to switch to "that person" or similar. The second time we reach "someone" in your sentence (2) it's more likely to be read as a second individual, as in:

Someone is running and someone is walking.

Obviously, the different verbs here make it unambiguous that the two "someone"s have to be different people, but it's the same when the sentence structure doesn't make it clear. "Someone else" is understood the second time, so it sounds like:

someone is not sure whether something someone else is about to say will be helpful or valued

And that's not the intent at all.
